# Fixing nginx 1.4.6 dependency on old openssl version (libssl0.9.8)?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ubuntu-12.04, openssl

I'm trying to enable TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance w/ nginx 1.4.6, but this version of nginx is dependent upon `libssl0.9.8`, even though the newest version of OpenSSL is installed (1.0.1).

How can I resolve this so I can enable TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2?

Comment: Recompile it? Or find the person who compiled it and yell at them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's an official amazon Ubuntu image, how would I recompile it?

Comment: Its being on Amazon is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Could you link to an article that could explain the process?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also, I wouldn't know what to recompile in particular.